# HTML5 video fallback - can't play video files in flash player locally

Tags: html, flash, html5-video, mp4, ogg

having a bit of a problem here that I cannot get my head around. I'm creating what is essentially an offline website which has various questions and videos which answer them. I have my videos in various formats to work on all browsers, mp4, ogv & webm.

I have been using the video for everyone generator to create my player, and that works fine. My flash fallback however for IE8 which doesn't support the `<video>` tag won't play my local files.

Here is my fallback code - housed inside my `<video></video>` element.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="640" height="360">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'..%2Fklacid%2Fvideos%2FMcGeer%2Fmp4%2FMc_7.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
    <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below"></span>
</object>
```

What is very strange is if I upload this video to my web server, and link it across - it will work fine.

Any solutions? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Jamie

Comment: Are you testing your website through a local web server (e.g., `http://localhost/`) or via `file:///`?

Comment: It is running directly though the file - file:/// - this is a requirement because the website may be run from a usb pen etc

Comment: `file:///` is subject to stricter security restrictions, which may be what you're running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only for local access, you must choose in the FLA's Publish Settings the Option **Access local files only** for Local playbac security.

For more information: http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/Flash%20Player%20Security%20Basics.html

Comment: More information here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000451.html